# Cannot generate c++ STL tag files for vim use

Tags: c++, vim, stl, tags, gdb

I'm a heavy vim user and often jump to function's implementation via ctrl-]. I wanna do the same thing for standard library. Here is how to generate tags file.

1. I have two versions of gcc/g++, one is system default 4.4.4 with source at usr/include/c++/4.4.4, and 4.9.1 with source at /opt/gcc/include/c++/4.9.1.
2. Command to generate tags file for 4.4.4 -

   > ctags -R --c++-kinds=+px --fields=+iaS --extra=+q
   >   /usr/include/c++/4.4.4

   This works well. After adding the generated tags file to vim, I can use ctrl-] without problem.
3. However I cannot get correct tags file for 4.9.1 with same command -

   > ctags -R --c++-kinds=+px --fields=+iaS --extra=+q /opt/gcc/include/c++/4.9.1

   The generated file size is much smaller than above version. I checked the tags file and functions' tag is not there.

Surprisingly, I can step into the STL source code (4.9.1) when debugging my program with gdb. I have same problem under CentOS 6 and 7.

What am I missing? Can anyone share idea?

Comment: You really want to look at std source?!  I would link to docs instead myself.

Comment: In case I need to take a look the function declaration.

Comment: You might start by replacing the long-dead Exuberant Ctags by [Universal Ctags](http://ctags.io/).

Comment: @SatoKatsura Yes, I did but gave same result.

Comment: Then post a bug report.  The project is actively maintained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks few devs use tags file for STL. Still no clear answer and Closed.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to get completion in vim for C++ STL using just ctags, and testing out stepping into STL source code it does work with gcc version 10

```
$ cp -R /usr/include/c++/$GCC_VERSION ~/.vim/cpp_src
# it is not necessary to rename headers without an extension
# replace the "namespace std _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default)" with "namespace std"
$ find . -type f | xargs sed -i 's/namespace std _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default)/namespace std/'
$ ctags -f cpp_tags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q --language-force=C++ -I _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT cpp_src
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24553063/6645454